# Binding multiple related variables in Clojure without nested let

Tags: clojure, nested, let

I want to use the value of a variable to compute the value of another variable in the same let statement. Is there a way to do this in Clojure without using nested lets?

Nested let solution:

```
(let [x 3] 
  (let [y (+ 1 x)] 
    y)) = 4
```

Desired solution:

```
(let [x 3 
      y (+ 1 x)] 
   y) = 4
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Never mind, the desired solution works fine. I wonder why I was having trouble with it before?

Comment: I just had the same issue, turns out I was using the variable within a quoted form and as such it was not evaluated.